Any examples of using rust-openssl to retrieve a 'othername' value for subject_alt_names()?
I'm using the rust-openssl crate to parse a X509 certificate.  I'm trying to get at a Subject Alternate Name field on that cert.
For the example cert snippet (from openssl x509 -text)
...
 X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                othername: UPN::myuser@somedomain.com
...


Take the following example code:
use std::fmt::Pointer;
use openssl::x509::{GeneralName, X509};
fn main() {
    static SOME_PEM: &str = "spikes/x509_parser/cert.pem";
    let data = std::fs::read(SOME_PEM).expect("Could not read file");
    let cert = X509::from_pem(data.as_slice()).expect("Could not load cert");

    let sans = cert.subject_alt_names().unwrap();

    println("SAN count: {}", b.len());

    for entry in  &b {
        # all of the below (unsurprisingly) result in None
        # entry.ipaddress() 
        # entry.email() 
        # entry.dnsname() 
    }
   }


There must be some way to try and get at the entry in the above example as a OtherName, but I can't figure out how.   There is not a entry.othername()...
Any help out there from the rusty ones?

You know, I don't think you can get the othername, at least not currently through the safe openssl Rust API. I see how the existing methods like email work, and there's a constant for GEN_OTHERNAME in the -sys crate but it looks like a method was never made for it. Sounds like a, hopefully easy, feature request (I didn't see any existing issues about it).

Thanks @kmdreko - yes that's what I see too; I figured I must be missing something but maybe it's just not possible as you say.   I'll see if I can add it.

Were you able to figure this out? Running into an identical problem.
